# Error in SqlConncetion in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I want to connect to a database in C# and I am following a tutorial video 
When I use this code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace @new
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Home\Documents\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I receive this error:

> Load of property 'RootNamespace' failed. The string for the root namespace must be a valid identifier.    new

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your connection string has unrecognizable escape characters. Use the verbatim literal `@` before the connection string to ignore all escape characters.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Home\Documents\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```